# Can std::move move a built-in types or c pointer or array

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmove

I have 3 questions:

1. Can `std::move` move a built-in type ?

```
int a = 10;
int b = std::move(a);
```

Will `a` be an invalid value?

---

2. Can `std::move` move a pointer

```
int *a = new int[10];
int *b = std::move(a);
```

Will `a` become an invalid pointer or `nullptr`?

---

3. can `std::move` move a c array?

```
struct S {
  int array[10];
}
S a;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  a.array[i]=1;
S b;
b = std::move(a);
```

Will `a.array` become an invalid array?

Answer (score 5):

`move` itself does nothing rather than a `static_cast`. According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

> It is exactly equivalent to a static_cast to an rvalue reference type.

Thus, it depends on the type of the variable you assign to after the `move`, if the type has `constructors` or `assign operators` that takes a rvalue parameter, it may or may not *steal* the content of the original variable, so, it may leave the original variable to be in an `unspecified state`:

> Unless otherwise specified, all standard library objects that have been moved from are placed in a valid but unspecified state.

Back to your questions, because there is no special `move constructor` or `move assign operator` for built-in literal types such as integers and raw pointers, so, it will be just a simple copy for these types. Thus, for question 1, and question 2, `a` is still valid and not changed after the `move`. Because C++ does not allow direct assignment for C array, so the code in question 3 does not compile.

--- edit ---

Your original 3rd question is assigning a plain C array to another, which is not allowed by the language.

Your updated 3rd question is different, it embeds a C array in a struct, and now you are assigning a struct to another, which can compile now. Because you does not have `move assign operator` for your struct, the default assignment operator is called, which does a byte level copying, thus, `a` is unchanged after the move and assignment.

This happens only if all member of the struct are POD (Plain Old Data). If you add a non-POD member into your struct, the assignment statement will not compile, because it can not use the default "byte level copy" assign operator to copy non-POD member (for example, a string object).

```
struct S {
  std::string something;  // non-POD member
  int array[100];
};
S a, b;
b = std::move(a);  // this line will not compile
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I had edited the 3rd question, now the array will be a  member of struct s, what will happen?

Comment: Code in your update 3rd question is fine, can compile, and a remains unchanged. I updated my answer accordingly. It's better to add a 4th question instead of replace the 3rd one, so that readers will not get confused :-).

Comment: BTW, you can accept this answer if it answered your question, it gives other readers a clear signal.