# why non-movable Object still a copy

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, rvalue

Consider the following code, Entity object is non-movable. I know that std::move(Obj) just cast the Obj to a rvalue reference Obj. And I also know that rvalue reference variable is still a lvalue object.  But I still confusing why statement `auto temp = std::move(a)` can call copy constructor, statement `a = std::move(b);` can call copy assignment operator. Since, std::move(a) is a rvalue reference, why it can still call lvalue constructor.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void my_swap(T& a, T& b) {
    auto temp = std::move(a);
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(temp);
}

class Entity{
    int _id;
public:
    Entity(int id) :_id(id)  {std::cout << "construtor\n" << std::endl;}
    Entity(const Entity& other) {
        _id = other._id;
        std::cout << "copy constructor\n" << std::endl;
    }

    Entity& operator= (const Entity& other) {
        if (&other == this) return *this;
        this->_id = other._id;
        std::cout << "copy assignment operator\n";
        return *this;
    }

};

int main() {
    Entity e1 = Entity(10);
    Entity e2 = Entity(20);
    my_swap(e1,e2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: temporary/rvalue reference can bind to const reference.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I know that the swap function in c++ library is implemented like  `my_swap`.  But how it make the assignment works for a non-movable object.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't movable?

Comment: The semantics of a move is that the source object has the value the moved from object "had".  It doesn't require the moved from object to be empty or to have any specific state.  If you preform a copy to do that, then you have technically satisfied the requirements.

Comment: @molbdnilo Suppose the class doesn't have a move constructor / assignment operator. Or make them delete.

Comment: @amont: Not having them and deleting them are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Entity object is non-movable

No. Even it doesn't have move constructor/assignment-operator, it has copy constructor/assignment-operator taking lvalue-reference to const. `std::move(a)` and `std::move(b)` are rvalue (xvalue) expressions and they could be bound to lvalue-reference to const.

You might also check [`std::is_move_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible#Notes):

> Types without a move constructor, but with a copy constructor that accepts const T& arguments, satisfy std::is_move_constructible.

Comment: thanks, i still wondering whether all of the built-in types have copy constructor with const T& arguments.

Comment: @amont No, built-in types doesn't have constructors, only class types could.

Comment: I still have one problem, I tested `int x = 10, y = 20; my_swap(x, y);`, it swapped success. Why `x = std::move(y)` still works？

Comment: @amont For built-in types move operation just performs copy. `x = std::move(y);` is just same as `x = y;` for built-in types.

Comment: Does there has some references. Thanks

Comment: @amont [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62630855/3309790)?

Answer (score 0):

> Considering the following code, Entity object is non-movable.

No, it isn't. `Entity` is movable.

> But I still confusing why statement auto temp = std::move(a)

Lvalue reference to const can be bound to an rvalue. The copy constructor accepts an lvalue reference to const parameter. That parameter can be bound to the `std::move(a)` rvalue argument.

> And I also know that rvalue reference variable is still a lvalue object.

Not quite. References are not objects. An id-expression that names anything, including an rvalue reference varaible, is an lvalue.

> Entity is movable. Does is because there exists default move constructor/assignment-operator.

It is movable because it has a copy constructor/assignment operator, and it doesn't have deleted move constructor/assignment operator.

Comment: > Entity is movable. 

Does is because there exists default move constructor/assignment-operator. Thanks

Comment: @amont See edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your `Entity` non-movable, then add the move-constructor and move-assignment operator as deleted:

```
    Entity(Entity&& other) = delete;
    Entity& operator= (Entity&& other) = delete;
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is a pointless exercise. It'll only annoy the users of your class, that's all.

Comment: _"Guideline: Never delete the special move members"_: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38820178/580083